# Ubuntu with green screen after booting from usb

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have formatted my usb in GPT partition (uefi mode)and installed windows 8 in my dell precision tower 7910 and also i made the same for ubuntu (GPT with uefi mode)
but when i come to boot the system, all i get is green and yellow screens as i have two screens. i tried nomodeset before quite splash and it helps me to pass the green screen and i installed successfully ubuntu but then when i restart my computer all i get is again green and yellow screens.
i have followed all the nividia problems non was working
anyway i have turned of my secure boot
hope to find help

Best regards

Comment: it works fine without secureboot?

Comment: actually nothing is working but what im doing is i dont run the secure boot as it was suggested by other answers

Comment: i'll i get is green and yellow screen

Comment: did you try nomodeset with the installed grub? it sounds like grub is trying to use a graphics mode that your computer doesn't support for boot

Comment: i did try nomodeset and actually nomodeset helped me to install the ubuntu but when i restart the computer after installing, computer turn to power saving mood

Comment: If you needed `nomodeset` before you need it as well in the installed OS, now and always, until you install the proprietary graphics drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu goes to power saving mode after installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935376/ubuntu-goes-to-power-saving-mode-after-installing-ubuntu)